# Doubts about Alphabetic complexity

Tags: algorithm

I'm beginner in Description complexity so i have some doubts to resolve many exercises. Maybe, can someone explainde me how to resolve this problem? also the main idea that involves this problem and maybe some interesting lectures. Thanks in advance.

> Alphabetic complexity

Rank the following structures based on their complexity:

d j x k

a a a a

p q r s

a b c d

w x y z

By default, a series of four letters requires 4 × log(26) bits, but we can do much better for several of these sequences (one needs log2(N) bits in general to represent one object taken among N objects; if the set of objects is ordered, the complexity of the nth one is at most log2(n)).

Provide indications showing how the complexity of the above structures can be computed. Be precise. Imagine a simple "machine" with a few avilable operations such as copy, increment, search, last; the machine may read several lists: list of operations, alphabet, list of lists. One needs a few bits to designate a list, plus more bits to designate an element in that list. The problem is to find the smallest designation of the object.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really tell what you mean by "complexity".  Perhaps you are looking for Kolmogorov Complexity?

Comment: Yes the notion of complexity was defined also by Kolmogorov.